# Is it possible to retrieve an object list (which was created from a JSON file) from another class?

Tags: ios, json, swift, class, variables

I am new in iOS programming and I have a question about getting a list built from another class. Let me explain :
I am trying to build a basic bike app, that allows user to see all bikes location in a map or in a tableview. When opening the app, first view is the map. I would like the map to be filled with annotation. Here is the thing : in the map view controller I call fetchStationData() that is defined in my table view controller class, which fills a global variable with bike station object. I want to get this global variable in the map VC to put all my annotations. In other words : I want my stationsList to be build only once when opening the app, and I want to be able to access data from this list in the tableview AND on the map, I don't want to reload the data twice from the JSON file.

I tried to print the object list after fetching data and I'm getting nothing.

```swift
// In Map VC file
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        StationListScreen().fetchStationData()
    }

private func setUpAnnotation() {
        for station in StationListScreen.stationsList {
            let location = station.location
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = station.stationName
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }

// In StationListScreen class
// Global var declaration

static var stationsList = [Station]()

// Fetching data function

func fetchStationData() {

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        let location = locationManager.location

        var allStations = [Station]()

        let jsonStringUrl = URL(string: "https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=velib-disponibilite-en-temps-reel&rows=2000")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonStringUrl!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else { return }
                guard let recordsObjects = jsonObject["records"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return }
                for recordObject in recordsObjects {
                    if let fields = recordObject["fields"] as? [String: AnyObject],
                        let nbFreeEDock = fields["nbfreeedock"] as? Int,
                        let nbBikes = fields["nbbike"] as? Int,
                        let nbEBikes = fields["nbebike"] as? Int,
                        let stationName = fields["station_name"] as? String,
                        let geo = fields["geo"] as? [CLLocationDegrees]
                    {
                        allStations.append(Station(stationName: stationName,nbBikes: nbBikes, nbEBikes: nbEBikes, nbFreeDocks: nbFreeEDock, location: Location(latitude: geo[0], longitude: geo[1]), distance: Int(location!.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: geo[0], longitude: geo[1]))) / 1000))
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    StationListScreen.self.stationsList = allStations
                }
            }
            catch {
                return
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

The tableview loads with every stations I need, so the call to the function did its work, but there is no annotation on the map (I know my annotation function is working and I call it, I just removed the call here)

Comment: Mobile isn't coded like that. You should repull from the data source and isolate views entirely. This is in part why mobile BaaS and PaaS backends are relying on graphQL and NoSQL for massive request loads. However, if you really want to do this, you do this in the singleton pattern, but you're playing with fire. And, you could also set up something like SQL lite local caching or use Realm. This caching mechanism would be "first cache, then data source/network".

Comment: Repulling from the data source means I should have the same function in two differents classes ? Else how can I do ?

Comment: yes, but you don't need to do that, you use the NSObject class to store all your netwroking functions and then import that class and call it's same function in both views. that's the easiest way to do this. you can start getting fancy by offloading your datasource into a separate file later, but I'd start here first.

Comment: How does the user switch between the tableview and mapview?  Are they in a tabbar, or are they children view controllers in a container, or are you presenting different view controllers from a button click?

Comment: Yes the switch is made with a tabbar

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton class for this purpose.. keep your stations data in that singleton class and use in TableViewController and in your MapView class.

Comment: How do I keep my stations data ? In a global variables ? I did what you say but I still have the same problem retrieving the data

Answer (score 0):

Update : I just tried to make the thread sleep during few seconds and it worked... I think the problem came from the data that was not retrieved from the request before my others functions were called... Is there a way to code : I want that function to be completely done before moving one to others ?